# Cannot find required file error when using SolutionPackager to pack Dynamics 365 solution in Azure Devops Build Step

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm attempting to use Azure DevOps pipelines to 'pack' (using Dynamics 365 CoreTools/SolutionPackager.exe) a solution from an Azure Repo to create the zip file as the artifact.

My Build Pipeline has the following steps.
Step 1: Install Solution Packager.
This is a powershell script which installs solution packager onto the build agent. For those trying to do what I'm doing here is the code.

```
$sourceNugetExe = "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
$targetNugetExe = ".\nuget.exe"
Remove-Item .\Tools -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore
Invoke-WebRequest $sourceNugetExe -OutFile $targetNugetExe
Set-Alias nuget $targetNugetExe -Scope Global -Verbose

./nuget install  Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools -O .\Tools
md .\Tools\CoreTools
$coreToolsFolder = Get-ChildItem ./Tools | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools.'}
move .\Tools\$coreToolsFolder\content\bin\coretools\*.* .\Tools\CoreTools
Remove-Item .\Tools\$coreToolsFolder -Force -Recurse

Remove-Item nuget.exe
```

Step 2: Create the solution.
This is also a powershell script which is as below.

```
Write-Host $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY

cmd.exe /c "$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\Tools\CoreTools\SolutionPackager.exe /action:Pack /zipfile:$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\Releases\Release1\PhoneBook.zip /folder:$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\DeploymentAutomation\PhoneBookSolutionExtract /packageType:Both /log:$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\Releases\Release1\PBSolutionPackagerLog-Packer.txt"
```

Step 1 runs successfully. However, step 2 fails with this error.

===========================================

```
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8552200Z ##[section]Starting: Create Solutions For Release
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8797381Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8827561Z Task         : PowerShell
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8835720Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8843310Z Version      : 2.169.0
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8849328Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8860104Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2020-05-26T15:28:59.8893584Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-26T15:29:00.8519134Z Generating script.
2020-05-26T15:29:00.8970243Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-05-26T15:29:00.9225660Z ##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'd:\a\_temp\d09c6a36-7a76-47b0-92eb-9e6107517075.ps1'"
2020-05-26T15:29:01.2594475Z d:\a\1\s
2020-05-26T15:29:01.7233931Z SolutionPackger CRM Solution Packaging Tool [Version 9.1.0.45]
2020-05-26T15:29:01.7243873Z Â© 2017 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved
2020-05-26T15:29:01.7249166Z 
2020-05-26T15:29:06.5096584Z 
2020-05-26T15:29:06.5110471Z Packing d:\a\1\s\DeploymentAutomation\PhoneBookSolutionExtract to d:\a\1\s\Releases\Release1\PhoneBook.zip and d:\a\1\s\Releases\Release1\PhoneBook_managed.zip
2020-05-26T15:29:06.5120793Z 
2020-05-26T15:29:06.6894038Z Cannot find required file 'd:\a\1\s\DeploymentAutomation\PhoneBookSolutionExtract\Other\Customizations.xml'.
2020-05-26T15:29:06.6906958Z See log file 'd:\a\1\s\Releases\Release1\PBSolutionPackagerLog-Packer.txt' for details.
2020-05-26T15:29:06.9902672Z SolutionPackager: Exception thrown: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.SolutionPackager.DiskReaderException: Cannot find required file 'd:\a\1\s\DeploymentAutomation\PhoneBookSolutionExtract\Other\Customizations.xml'.
2020-05-26T15:29:06.9924366Z    at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.SolutionPackager.DiskReader.Load()
2020-05-26T15:29:06.9938677Z    at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.SolutionPackager.SolutionPackager.Run(IPackageReader reader, IPackageWriter writer)
2020-05-26T15:29:06.9950963Z    at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.SolutionPackager.SolutionPackager.Run()
2020-05-26T15:29:06.9962227Z    at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.SolutionPackager.Program.Main(String[] args), returning error code '1'
2020-05-26T15:29:07.2240607Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-05-26T15:29:07.2727244Z ##[section]Finishing: Create Solutions For Release
```

===========================================

I've checked atleast a 1000 times and the file Customizations.xml DOES EXIST at the location specified. This might be something really stupid that I'm missing, as this is the FIRST time I'm trying to automate a Dynamics 365 deployment using Azure DevOps Pipelines, so any help in understanding this error will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot find required file ......Other\Customizations.xml

According to the error message, this issue is related with the `/folder` parameter.

I test the similar SolutionPackager.exe command. If the Customizations.xml exists,the powershell task will success.

[image: Zip File]

So you need to make sure that the **folder path** is correct.

On the one hand, you can export the file structure as suggested by Eric Smith. Then you could modify the path.

On the other hand，you could try to add a "Copy files" task before the Step 2.

Please use `...` to select the folder

[image: Copy file task]

If the files have existed in the folder, the task log will show the information.

[image: file exists]

If they don't exist, these files will be copied to the specified location.

BTW, please make sure you have selected the **correct branch** to run the build

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Your suggestion led me to the solution. School boy error. I needed the copy step before the pack step to copy the files to the build server. Once I did that, everything worked perfectly. I was checking the repository but I shouldve been checking for the file's existence on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

I will jump in and try to help. I have not dealt with SolutionPackager.exe much but following [this tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft-d365-ce-pfe-devops/D365-CE-DevOps-Tutorial) I was able to extract and then pack a solution. Are you able to do the Pack locally?

Assuming you ran the extract command locally and then commited everything to your repository. How sure are you that the Customizations.xml is actually checked into the repository and resident in the sources directory?

You can go and double check in the repository itself or you can also use this yaml snippet to print out a tree of the directory structure for a sanity check.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: tree $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'tree /F'
    pwsh: true
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```